# Android optimisation and portability

Tags: java, android

I've been developing java for several years, and i'm thinking of trying to android application development , even if i'm a little late in the game.

How would I go about limiting the memory usage and battery usage of an android application?

and also, what kind of portability issues will I face when writing android apps?

Comment: Your question is too general. Try to develop Android applications and ask a question about a specific memory / portability problem you are meeting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one depends heavily on the used hardware (GPS, Wifi, ...) and of course it depends what your app will be.

The portability is basically like web development: You will see when you stumble upon them. With experience you will implement workarounds you remember before you hit the wall...

Comment: I have heard people say that you have to allocate memory to your application, if this is correct, could you give me an example line of code for this?

Comment: Do you allocate memory in java? Only in very rare situations (like OpenGL ES) you need to. If you have `several years` experience in Java, you should find it pretty easy to dive into Android programming. Just start! It is just a framework you need to learn to use...